# How to correctly display the date?

Tags: reactjs

How to correctly display the date?

After registration, the user writes his date in the format - 09/09/1997, then I do:

```
  handleDateChange = e => {
    let birthDate = new Date(e.target.value)
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: birthDate, bannerText: '', birthDate: e.target.value })
  }
```

Then I do getTime () to send what the user entered into the database:

```
  buildRequest = field => {
    console.log(field)
    return {
      [field]:
        this.state[field] instanceof Date
          ? this.state[field].getTime() // birthday
          : this.state[field],
    }
  }
```

My input:

```
        <InputDate
          id={'user-birthday'}
          actionLabel={this.getDateActionLabel('birthday')}
          label={'Мой день рождения'}
          value={this.state.birthday}
          onChange={e => this.handleDateChange(e)}
          name={'birthday'}
          showMobileActionLabel={true}
          className={safariClassName}
          onConfirm={this.editInfo}
          disabled={!this.getDateActionLabel('birthday')}
          placeholder={'Ваш день рождения'}
          error={this.state.birthdayError}
        />
```

How to make the input value of this format, after the user entered - **09/09/1997**?

**Now I have it: 09.19.9700**

*I use react-input-mask*

Answer (score 0):

Did you try mask attribute?
you can put mask="11/11/1111" or mask="11.11.1111" or any format you preferred on InputDate element.